# Help Directing Question to Appropriate Forum Area, Please: Repository Issue in 20.04

Tags: package-management, ppa, repository

I am using **Ubuntu 20.4** and I am attempting to install **DSD** by debi http://ppa.launchpad.net/szechyjs/dsd/ubuntu 20.4 main

**But** I get this response:

```
debi: warning:     debian/changelog(l12): found start of entry where expected more change data or trailer
LINE: sdrangel (6.7.0-1) unstable; urgency=medium
debi: warning:     debian/changelog(l12): found end of file where expected more change data or trailer
debi: can't read sdrangel_6.8.0-1_amd64.changes!
```

The developer of DSD really wants us to use DOCKER to install full versions of SDRAngel, which includes DSD, so I tried that, as well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

**BUT** I receive this response:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                    
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                        
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                      
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/szechyjs/dsd/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                              
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/szechyjs/dsd/ubuntu focal Release                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [264 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [303 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,768 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.3 kB]       
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58.2 kB]
Reading package lists... Done               
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/szechyjs/dsd/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It appears from these two responses that the DSD component for Ubuntu 20.04 is absent. It appears that past and future releases of Ubuntu have valid DSD repositories. 20.04 seems to have an abnormally ended file repository. I am assuming here that the DSD repository needs to be rebuilt and replaced, then the Docker container for 20.04 be rebuilt and replaced.

I left a note with the DSD developer yesterday in github, but no response as of this afternoon from anyone.

I don't know where is the appropriate forum to lodge this issue. I would have assumed the repository should have been submitted by the DSD developer. But, I can see the potential that the Ubuntu repository build might be managed by someone other than the developer, so maybe a repository maintainer issue. In the case of the Docker container, it might be some issue with the container publishing function.

Can those familiar with this whole process advise me on how to properly direct this (these?) issue(s)?

Many thanks,
Shane

Comment: That PPA doesn't support *focal* or 20.04, it's support ended in 18.04/bionic.  PPA's are 3rd party sources so all security checks are on you, did you perform any? as https://launchpad.net/~szechyjs/+archive/ubuntu/dsd would have indicated it's been unsupported for some time..  (145 weeks ago was sometime before *focal* was ....)   You can file a bug with the owner of the PPA but it's a *personal package archive* so it's competely up to the owner if/when they support/drop-support as it's not a Ubuntu repository.

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party repositories (*personal package archive* as per my prior comment), which yes are built on Ubuntu/Canonical infrastructure, but all support for them is 3rd party or the *person* who owns/builds it thus all security checks are your responsibility. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu   The building of packages only is performed on Canonical infrastructure so we have security on the builds, but all support & what is built is 3rd party.  FYI: this isn't a forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is that

Answer (score 1):

If you look up

[https://launchpad.net/~szechyjs/+archive/ubuntu/dsd](https://launchpad.net/%7Eszechyjs/+archive/ubuntu/dsd)

You'll note the user "[Jared](https://launchpad.net/%7Eszechyjs)" owns the *personal package archive* and the page I used has a question & bug link where you can speak with the owner of the PPA/personal package archive.

As I stated in comments

PPA's are 3rd party repositories, which yes are built on Ubuntu/Canonical infrastructure, but all support for them is 3rd party or the person who owns/builds it thus all security checks are your responsibility. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

The building of packages only is performed on Canonical infrastructure so we have security on the builds, but all support & what is built is 3rd party.

FYI: this isn't a forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is that

Comment: @gulverc,Thank you so much for your kind guidance and suggestions! I will attempt to contact the ppa owner.